# What is the expectation of a random variable divided by an average $E\left[\frac{X_i}{\bar{X}}\right]$?

Tags: probability, random-variable, expected-value

Let $X_i$ be IID and $\bar{X} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$.
$$
E\left[\frac{X_i}{\bar{X}}\right] = \ ?
$$
It seems obvious, but I am having trouble formally deriving it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be independent and identically distributed random variables and define $$\bar{X}=\frac{X_1+X_2\dots+X_n}{n}.$$

Suppose that $\Pr\{\bar{X}\ne 0\}=1$. Since the $X_i$'s are identically distributed, symmetry tells us that, for $i=1,\dots n$, the (dependent) random variables $X_i/\bar{X}$ have the same distribution:
$$
  \frac{X_1}{\bar{X}} \sim \frac{X_2}{\bar{X}} \sim \dots \sim \frac{X_n}{\bar{X}}.
$$
If the expectations $\mathrm{E}[X_i/\bar{X}]$ exist (this is a crucial point), then
$$
\mathrm{E}\left[ \frac{X_1}{\bar{X}} \right] = \mathrm{E}\left[ \frac{X_2}{\bar{X}} \right] = \dots = \mathrm{E}\left[ \frac{X_n}{\bar{X}} \right],
$$
and, for $i=1,\dots,n$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}\left[ \frac{X_i}{\bar{X}} \right] &= \frac{1}{n} \left( \mathrm{E}\left[ \frac{X_1}{\bar{X}} \right] + \mathrm{E}\left[ \frac{X_2}{\bar{X}} \right] + \dots + \mathrm{E}\left[ \frac{X_n}{\bar{X}} \right] \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{n}\,\mathrm{E}\left[ \frac{X_1}{\bar{X}} + \frac{X_2}{\bar{X}} + \dots + \frac{X_n}{\bar{X}} \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{n}\,\mathrm{E}\left[ \frac{X_1+X_2+\dots+X_n}{\bar{X}} \right] \\ 
&= \frac{1}{n}\,\mathrm{E}\left[ \frac{n\bar{X}}{\bar{X}} \right] \\
&= \frac{n}{n}\,\mathrm{E}\left[ \frac{\bar{X}}{\bar{X}} \right] = 1.
\end{align}
$$

Let's see if we can check this by simple Monte Carlo.

```
x <- matrix(rgamma(10^6, 1, 1), nrow = 10^5)
mean(x[, 3] / rowMeans(x))

[1] 1.00511
```

Fine, and the results don't change much under repetition.

Comment: I have always wondered about the notational  for this. Is $X_{1}|X \sim X_{2}|X ...$ the way to indicate that the resulting distribution will be the same, but the R.V.s will not be independent. You posted the answer as I was pondering how to write this out, so might as well get my doubts cleared too

Comment: (+1) The conclusion that $E[X_i/\bar X]$ does not exist is true, but requires a subtler argument than any of those you have yet linked to, because $X_i$ and $\bar X$ are not independent.

Comment: @whuber: Can you expand this a little bit, Bill? I mentioned the dependence of $X_i$ and $\bar{X}$ in one of the comments to the linked question. Also, Xi'an's answer addresses the $n=2$ case with a simple transformation. He also gave the distribution of $X_i/\bar{X}$ in one of his comments. Thank you for your thoughts on this.

Comment: @whuber: I think my explanation works out since$$X_i/\bar{X}=n/\{1+X_2/X_1+\cdots+X_n/X_1\}$$which is $n/\{1+(n-1)Z\}$, $Z$ being a standard Cauchy. No dependence involved.

Comment: @Xi'an: did you use here that (consider the $n=3$ case), since $U=X_2/X_1$ and $V=X_3/X_1$ are standard Cauchy, then $(U+V)/2$ is also standard Cauchy? But that's not true because $U$ and $V$ are not independent, right?

Comment: @Zen: However, $(X_2+\cdots+X_n)$ and $X_1$ are independent Normal variates, hence $(X_2+\cdots+X_n)/X_1$ is a Cauchy, if with a $\sqrt{n-1}$ scale rather than $n-1$.

Comment: OK, now it's totally clear.